# No TypeTag available when calling typeOf

Tags: scala

I have following code that is using `typeOf` from `scala.reflect.runtime.universe._`

```
 @Test
  def testTypeOf(): Unit = {
    import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
    def getTypeRefInfo[T: TypeTag](x: T): (Type, Symbol, Seq[Type]) = {
      val TypeRef(pre, sym, args) = typeOf[T]
      (pre, sym, args)
    }

    println(getTypeRefInfo(10))
    println(getTypeRefInfo(Seq(1, 3.14)))

    case class Box[T: TypeTag](val data: T)
    case class Person(age: Int)

    //ERROR:No TypeTag available for Box[Int]
    println(getTypeRefInfo(Box(1)))

    //ERROR: No TypeTag available for Box[Person]
    println(getTypeRefInfo(Box(Person(1))))
  }
```

The above code results in compiling errors, complaining `No TypeTag available for Box[Int]` and `No TypeTag available for Box[Person]`

I would ask what leads to this problem and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that the case class should be top level(Do not define it in method).